# getting error while concatinating string in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to show company name in code word like Dell Computers = DC  , but getting error in concatenating string.

```
         string str = txtCompanyname.Text.Trim();

            string[] output = str.Split(' ');
            foreach (string s in output)
            {
               // Console.Write(s[0] + " ");
                Response.Write(s[0]);
                string newid += s[0].ToString();//getting error here

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `NewID` outside the foreach loop. You can't define and assign the variable at the same time.

```
 string str = txtCompanyname.Text.Trim();
 string[] output = str.Split(' ');
 string newid= string.empty;
 foreach (string s in output)
  {
     // Console.Write(s[0] + " ");
        Response.Write(s[0]);
        newid += s[0].ToString();//getting error here

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string str = txtCompanyname.Text.Trim();

        string[] output = str.Split(' ');
        foreach (string s in output)
        {

            Response.Write(s);
            string newid += s;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using linq.

Just split the full name and select first character of every part;

```
string str = "Dell Computers";
var abbr = new string(str.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => char.ToUpper(x[0]))
    .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
public string FirstLetters(string s)
{
    return String.Join("", s.Trim().Split(' ').Select(w => w.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()));
}

var result = FirstLetter(txtCompanyname.Text);
```

This code does the following:

1. Trims your string
2. Splits your string by whitespace into a collection of separate words
3. Generates a collection by taking first uppercase letter from every word
4. Combines the collection of letters to a string